# How to bind Preferences with List

Tags: android

I think I read this somewhere, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Is there a way to bind preferences with a ListView so that onListItemClick, so I can edit or delete the preference without having to do the bookkeeping myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `ListView` for this. Assuming its done from within `PreferenceActivity`

```
//setting the click listener
Preference somePref = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("preference");
somePref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {            
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(preference);            
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: If I wanted to edit or delete it in a different Activity, is it okay to pass the preference around?

Comment: Nope. If you want to delete preferences from `SharedPreferences`, use its methods. `PreferenceActivity` is only UI, it does not effect the actual stored values; it may not show all values or show values that are really not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`PreferenceActivity` sounds like what you want. I don't know why you'd want to 'delete' a preference though.